# Disappointed of VBA's performance

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a very simple macro in Excel to remove some trailing excessive text. here is the code:

```
Sub remove_excess_names_from_part_number()
    Dim i As Integer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 1 To 1000
        Cells(i, 3).Value = Left(Cells(i, 3).Value, 10)
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I cannot see how this can get any simpler and yet I am disappointed by the poor Performance of this code snippet. Doesn't VBA make some optimizations for simple code like that?

Comment: Interaction with the spreadsheet is notoriously slow: load the data at once, manipulate it and put it back in the spreadsheet at once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below code :

Column C is result Column and data is in Column A

```
Sub remove_excess_names_from_part_number()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("C1:C" & lastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=Left(RC[-2],10)"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, a lot faster! Thanks for the quick answer!

Answer (score 3):

Do you really need VBA for this? If you want you can use Excel's Text To Columns

Let's say the data is like this in Excel

[image]

1. Select your column and Click on Data | Text To Columns
2. Select `Fixed Width` in Step 1 of 3
3. Set your length in Step 2 of 3. If you see below, I have set it for `10`
4. Click Finish and you are done.

[image]

**Note**: If the 10th character is a `SPACE` then it will be truncated as in Row 2

[image]

If you still want a VBA solution then I would recommend loading the entire range in an Array as @assylias suggested and then put it back after performing the calculations.

@Santosh has also given you a suggestion when you can enter the formula in one go to all the cells. If Non VBA option is available to you then you can enter the formula in the cell manually and do an autofill as well :)

Comment: Interesting solution that I didn't know about. Thanks. I will test which solution proves to be more practical for my needs.

Comment: If you are open to Non VBA Solution then typing the formula in the spreadsheet directly for few thousand rows and doing an Autofill is the best option. If you have very large data then `Text to Columns` will prove faster as compared with the formula or the VBA code.

Comment: After giving it a few tries I have to say that this is a very nice solution, if the text of interest is really perfectly the same all the time.